# Hibernate c3p0 maxPoolSize in high load web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, c3p0

This is a general question about the configuration of the c3p0 connection pool manager, in high load web applications.
We're using hibernate as our ORM in a web application, and we're using c3p0 as our connection pool manager. Our current configuration looks like this:

```
    final com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource();

    PropertyHelper propertyHelper = new PropertyHelper("db.properties");
    String jdbcUrl = propertyHelper.read("jdbcUrl");
    String user = propertyHelper.read("dbuser");
    String password = propertyHelper.read("dbpass");

    dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
    dataSource.setUser(user);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    dataSource.setMinPoolSize(3);
    dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(1);
    dataSource.setTestConnectionOnCheckin(true);
    dataSource.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(140);
    dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(200);
    dataSource.setMaxStatements(0);
    dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(300);
```

What we notice in profiling, when load testing our REST API (interfacing to the database), is that the connection pool manager is taking up almost all of the time. With 500 threads querying the API for different resources every 1 seconds, it works alright, with a average response time of 25-50 ms. However, as soon as we get above that, say 2000 threads querying the API, the requests start taking 1-3 seconds, with the connection pool manager taking up 90% of the request time.

As soon as we bunk down the amount of requests again, the connection pool manager starts being able to follow again, and we're back to 25-50 ms per request. The profiling shows no signs of memory leaks.

My question is, what the correct way to configure the connection pool manager is, when you have a web application that should be able to handle thousands of requests every second. I've not been able to find best practices on the area, other that default/recommended max_pool_size spanding between 5 and 100, depending on where you're reading.

I hope someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

I found my answer in [this article](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) recommended by @Kayaman. A good formula to start out with, when choosing your connection pool size, is the following, supplied by PostgreSQL:

**connections = ((core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)**

I definitely have something to work from now.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220409/how-to-choose-maximum-connection-pool-size

Comment: HikariCP has a very good [article](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) on connection pool sizing, as well as having pretty much the best connection pool on the free market.

Comment: Can your database handle this number of queries? What happens when you increase connection pool size?

Comment: @kostya I've tried to increase the max pool size to 1000 - but i'm not aware of the consequences of doing so, as it would require me to increasy the max_connection of the database itself. What can be the consequences of increasing the max_connections of the database itself, performance-wize? Is it only a question of memory usage?

Comment: Never mind. I just read the article posted by @Kayaman, and it was just what I needed. Thanks!